# Is $[1,5]$ an open set?

Tags: general-topology

Wikipedia page for [open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) gives two definitions for the open set:

**First**
A subset $U$ of the Euclidean $n$-space $\mathbb R^n$ is called open if, given any point $x$ in $U$, there exists a real number $ε > 0$ such that, given any point $y$ in $\mathbb R^n$ whose Euclidean distance from $x$ is smaller than $ε$, $y$ also belongs to $U$.

**Second**
All elements of $T$ where

1. The trivial subsets are in T.
2. Whenever sets $A$ and $B$ are in $T$, then so is $A$ intersection $B$.
3. Whenever two or more sets are in $T$, then so is their union

Consider the topology of $\mathbb R$.

Now, according to the first definition, $[1,5]$ is not open because there exists no ε>0 such that $5+ε$ is in $[1,5]$.

However, we now let $T$ be the family of all subsets of $\mathbb R$.

We can see that $T$ satisfies all $3$ conditions outlined in the second definition. Thus, all elements of $T$ are open, which includes $[1,5]$.

Now, obviously one of these must be wrong. It should be the second one, but I don't see why exactly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The notion of open sets varies along with the underground topology.

Comment: So, does that mean that both the results are correct in their respective contexts?

Comment: In this case, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The first definition uses the *standard topology* on $\mathbb{R}$, while the second is the more general definition of a topology. In your example, you simply created a *different* topology (the discrete topology) on $\mathbb{R}$.